# Duration of query increased when selecting only a few fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in a Database and I am querying it with MySQL Workbench. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2
    ON t1.Field1 = t2.Field2
    AND t1.Field2 = t2.Field2
    AND t1.Field3 = t2.Field3
    AND t1.Field4 = t2.Field4
WHERE t1.Field5 = 'XXXX'
LIMIT 500;
```

The `Duration/Fetch` times according to MySQL are **1.400 sec / 10 sec** (approximately) and it brings 500 rows and 21 columns (I find the fetch time a bit too much for this result, by the way).

But, what surprises me a lot is that when I select just a few fields, the Duration time increases. `Duration / Fetch` times are around **8.5 sec / 0 sec** for a query like the following:

```
SELECT t1.Field1,t1.Field2,t2.Field10 FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2
    ON t1.Field1 = t2.Field2
    AND t1.Field2 = t2.Field2
    AND t1.Field3 = t2.Field3
    AND t1.Field4 = t2.Field4
WHERE t1.Field5 = 'XXXX'
LIMIT 500;
```

Total time is a little higher when a select all fields (*) but "Duration" is much faster. I was expecting to have similar durations for both queries and a great speed increase in fetch time when requesting just a few fields. What am I missing here?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Step 1. Never use `SELECT *`. Step 2. See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I think you're focusing on the wrong end of the lollipop. The main factor in query performance is ususally indexes.

Comment: And note that `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`is fairly meaningless.

Comment: Assuming that you have indices that cover all fields that you join on, your first query would not need to traverse `t2` at all. The second query introduced `t2.Field10` into the picture.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean when you say "our first query would not need to traverse t2 at all" ? What is wrong with including "SELECT [...] t2.Field10"?